# Fantasy book series about a young girl and a talking dog solving mysteries

Tags: story-identification, books

This one was known to me years ago, but I don't recall much so I'll do my best in detailing what i remember:

- Most of the cover used in the series had a dark blue color in the background, with some other containing more color/being colorful.
- The "talking" dog usually had weird clothes or apparel on him (pretty sure it was a male dog). I vaguely recall the dog having a monocle/or glasses in one of the book series
- I don't exactly recall any of the story used in the book from the said series, but I do recall it had all the usual/recurrent ingredient/stereotypes from certain TV trope (which I'll detail on more below)
- One enemy in the series was being called "shadow" or coming from the shadows...Not sure of their exact name but it was a recurring theme in one of the story at some point
- The cover of most of the book in the series have the girl and dog being drawn in the middle with varying expressions
- The dog could sometimes see or hear things the girl couldn't (eg: hear voices, see strange figures etc)
- The dog sometimes was seen wearing human-like clothing that was fitting to him
- In one of the book, I vaguely recall the dog wearing a kilt (red/with red pattern on it)
- The girl sometimes had a magnifying glass in one of her hand
- The girl isn't tall at all (mentioning the covers depicting her since I don't know the detail of her exact height) and the dog is mostly on all fours, even though he seems to show human emotions/tendencies...

Details on the "stereotypes":

- There was one book in the series where you could clearly see the dog becoming "evil" or at least, foreshadowing that (based on the cover where the shadow/figure of the dog was drawn, and the summary of the said book described the girl noticing the dog "acting" strange)
- A Talking dog
- A group of individuals solving mysteries

That's all I can remember. I don't recall how many book there is in the series, but I know there more than 4 at least...

I'm unsure if the dog was clearly talking to the girl or "talking" as in, communicating to her in other way than speak, or if the girl just understood him and interpreted what he meant (but it was described so well, it *looked* like he was talking, so It's hard to say given it was a long time I read this).

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did the dog stand upright or walk on all fours?

Comment: It was walking on all four on most cover i seen (but not sure if he was ever described walking on two in any of the book). And I don't recall the exact year, but I'd say between 2008-2010 was when i read it (don't think I know the publication date though) @LogicDictates

Comment: Too recent, but https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/53585052-paws-in-the-action

Comment: hmm, sadly this isn't this :/ No dark blue color in the background, (and it's too colorful, whereas most of the covers had either the aforementioned color or some colorful ones, albeit less than the one in the link you mentioned). The dog doesn't seem "special" like the one i described either, and the girl in the cover is too tall (guess I'll edit detail on how tall she is). Thanks for trying nonetheless :D @FuzzyBoots

Comment: I'd try [this forum on goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/group/show/185-what-s-the-name-of-that-book)

Comment: I guess i will thanks? But I would be surprised if this is even on goodreads given it's maybe older than when i read it (as in, older than when i read it 10 years ago, since i don't know it's publication date) @clayRay

Comment: Possibly *The Talking Dog Detective Agency* series of 6 books? The dog on the covers doesn't wear a monocle or anything, though. https://www.amazon.com/Talking-Dog-Detective-Agency-Book/dp/B08JVPGT9F

Comment: hmm, Not this either I'm afraid. The one i described in my post was actually more on the "animated" side, when it come to the cover i mean (it was cartoon-like when it come drawing) @KlausÆ.Mogensen Will edit this in my post, my bad for forgetting to mention this :)

Comment: @NordineLotfi - from looking at some other book searches, many people answering questions here have a great knowledge of older, no longer published books

Comment: This is likely the legendary canine detective, **[Ralph von Wau Wau](http://www.pjfarmer.com/WORKS-series-ralph.html)**, however I don't have access to the two published short stories ("A Scarletin Study" and "The Doge Whose Barque was Worse Than His Bight") to confirm most of the details.